# Finding Burton's elementery number theory tough, any lower level book suggestion

Tags: advice

I am studying number theory from David Burton's book elementary analysis and second chapter on primes, in that exercise I had no idea how to start attempting questions on primes. The first chapter was ok though. Am I doing something wrong here ?  This is first time I am doing number theory by myself. Should I look for some other book ?
Thanks

Comment: Burton is pretty straightforward.  I know of a couple books that  I consider lower level, but they're not as well-written as Burton.   I don't think they would help you.  Try posting a specific question with your thoughts and attempts.

Comment: in first chapter there are examples and then exercises. in second chapter of primes, there is no solved question. just theorems and then exercises.. thats where i am stuck i find it to be very hard even to start a question

Comment: Try this book: https://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/frint.html

Comment: @lhf Thanks. what do you think about underwood dudleys book ?